# Parcelable object with user data types?

Tags: android, android-intent, serialization

Hey guys ive found some tutorials about sending non primitive object to activity via intent. But see only  that they have members of only primitive in all examples.

I have a class with members that are user data types.

How do i send an object with implementing Parcelable with non primitive instance variables like arraylist  etc?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The objects that are members of your class must also be Parcelable (or Serializable), and any objects they include must also be Parcelable (or Serializable). To summarize, a Parcelable object must have fields that are either: primitives, Parcelable objects (and their supported collections such as Map or ArrayList) or Serializable objects(and their supported collections such as Map or ArrayList).

A sample piece of code demonstrating this (the Foo class is a Parcelable which contains Bar, which is also Parcelable), is the following (in Java):

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Foo implements Parcelable {

    private int primitive;
    private Bar object;

    public Foo() {
        primitive = 0;
        object = null;
    }

    private Foo(final Parcel in) {
        primitive = in.readInt();
        object = in.readParcelable(Bar.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(primitive);
        dest.writeParcelable(object, flags);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Foo> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Foo>() {
        public Foo createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Foo(in);
        }

        public Foo[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Foo[size];
        }
    };
}
```

and the Bar class:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Bar implements Parcelable {
    private String attribute;

    public Bar() {
        attribute = "";
    }

    private Bar(final Parcel in) {
        attribute = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(attribute);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Bar> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Bar>() {
        public Bar createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Bar(in);
        }

        public Bar[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Bar[size];
        }
    };
}
```